# Pasar un valor asociado de un datagridview a un combobox

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo esta tabla que se relaciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con esta otra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo un `datagridview` y dos formularios, en uno esta el `datagridview` y en el otro un `combobox` y `textbox` para ingresar los datos, en el `combobox` muestro la columna **AbreviaturaTipoDoc** y cuando se guarda me muestra en el `datagridview` la columna **NombreTipDoc**, mi problema es que cuando intento editar el registro que selecciono en el `datagridview`, en el `combobox` no me sale la **Abreviatura** correcta, solo me muestra el primer registro, lo llamo asi:

```
frmEditar.cmbDocument.Text = dgvClientes.CurrentRow.Cells["NombreTipDoc"].Value.ToString();
```

por ejemplo si intento editar un registro que contenga el nombre **Documento Nacional de Identidad** al abrirse el `form`, en vez de que en el `combobox` mostrarme **DNI-CEDULA** me muestra es **RUC** por defecto porque es el primer campo del `combobox`. Siempre me pasa el `Value` con el nombre por defecto **Documento Nacional de Identidad** y no con su valor de **IdTipoDoc** que seria 3, hay alguna manera de que cuando se apriete Editar en el `combobox` aparezca la **abreviatura** correspondiente?

Comment: Podrías poner el método completo, por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde un form no puedes, ni debes acceder a los controles del otro form de forma directa, ya que por lo general estos aun no se cargan hasta tanto no realices el `Show()` del form, es por eso que se usa el constructor para pasar valores como datos simples.

Por otro lado asignar el `NombreTipDoc` desde el datagridview tampoco es util, es por eso que no debes pasar toda la info de un form al otro, sino solo el `id` del `cliente` que quieres editar y despues en el otro form recuperas los datos de ese registro.

```
public class FormEdicion : Form
{
    private readonly int _idCliente;

    public FormEdicion()
    {
        InitializeComponente();
    }

    public FormEdicion(int idCliente) : this()
    {
        _idCliente = idCliente;
    }

    public void FormEdicion_Load()
    {
        CargarComboTiposDocumentos();

        CargarCliente(_idCliente);
    }

    private void CargarComboTiposDocumentos()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();   
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string"))   
        {   
            string query = "select IdTipoDoc, NombreTipoDoc from <tabla>";   

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);   

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);     
            da.Fill(dt);   
        } 

        combobox1.DisplayMember = "NombreTipoDoc"; 
        combobox1.ValueMember = "IdTipoDoc"; 
        combobox1.Datasource = dt; 
    }

    private void CargarCliente(int idCliente)
    {
        string connstring = "connection string";  
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connstring)) 
        {  
            cn.Open();  

            string sql = "SELECT IdTipoDoc_Cliente, ... FROM <tabla> WHERE idCliente = @id";  
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);  
            cmd.Parameters.AddwithValue("@id", idCliente);  

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();  

            if (reader.Read())  
            {  
                combobox1.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(reader["IdTipoDoc_Cliente"]);  
                //otros campos 
            }  

        } 
    }

}
```

Entonces desde el form que tiene el grid lo invocas usando

```
public class FormListadoClientes : Form
{

    public void dgvClientes_CellClick(...)
    {
        int idCliente = Convert.ToInt32(dgvClientes.CurrentRow.Cells["IsCliente"].Value);

        FormEdicion frmEdicion = new FormEdicion(idCliente);
        frmEdicion.Show();

    }
}
```

La idea es que solo pasando el `idCliente` que seleccionas puedas en el otro form recuperar los datos de todo el registro y asignar el `SelectedValue` del combo de tipos de documento

Comment: Gracias Leandro por la respuesta